# Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I followed [Easy WCF Security and authorization of users](https://www.developerhandbook.com/wcf/easy-wcf-security-authorization-users/) article and getting `SecurityNegotiationException` exception on calling the service.

Full exception is

> 'Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
>   with authority 'peoplesite.local'.'

Inner exceptions are

> WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not
>   establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

and

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according
>   to the validation procedure.

After validating the certificate forcefully using following code

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
                {
                    return true;
                };
```

The exception changes to

> EndpointNotFoundException: 'The message with To
>   'https://peoplesite.local/PeopleService/RNS.Services.PeopleService.svc'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's
>   EndpointAddresses agree.'

I am using VS 2017 Community and using `WCF Service Library` project. Both the service and client are on the same machine.

What is wrong? Have i made any mistake? Or the article is not compatible with the project type?